# HP Proliant DL80 Gen9 cannot connect to iLO

Tags: windows-server-2016, hp, hp-proliant, remote-access, ilo

I have a second hand HP Proliant DL80 Gen9 server that was purchased without any instructions or passwords details, I'm trying to connect to ILO so I can install Windows etc using a USB as I do not have a monitor to do so. This model does not have a dedicated ILO port, but 2 ethernet cards' with ip addresses that known to me (when I ping I get a reply) but I'm unable to connect to them using the browser over http, any idea how I can access ILO on this server without a monitor?

Comment: check what you have got as error from the browser, in case of http issue update the firmware and update to a self created ssl certificate to solve that

Comment: No response, not even certificate warning

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping and telnet that IP successfully on 80 or 443? if so then the problem is browser config prohibiting TLS version which you should be able to change.

Comment: Yes, I can, but still no response, not even a certificate warning

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to configure iLO to use custom ports, shut down specific connections or filter by authorized list.

If you have no idea what the settings could be the easiest recovery is to reset iLO 4 to factory defaults via server setup:

> 1. From the **System Utilities** screen, select **System Configuration > iLO 4 Configuration Utility > Set to factory defaults**, and press **Enter**.
>
>    The iLO 4 Configuration Utility prompts you to select **YES** or **NO**.
> 2. Select **YES**, and press **Enter**.
> 3. When prompted to confirm the reset, press Enter.
>
>    iLO resets to the factory default settings. If you are managing iLO remotely, the remote console session is automatically ended.
> 4. Resume the boot process:
>
>    a. Optional: If you are managing iLO remotely, wait for the iLO reset to finish, and then start the iLO remote console.
>
>    The iLO 4 Configuration Utility screen is still open from the previous session.
>
>    b. Press **Esc** until the main menu is displayed.
>
>    c. Select **Exit and Resume Boot** in the main menu, and press **Enter**.
>
>    d. When prompted to confirm the request, press **Enter** to exit the screen and resume the boot process.

https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/proliant_uefi/UEFI_TM_030617/s_reset_ilo_defaults.html

Without monitor and keyboard, you'd have to resort to scanning ports and finding access to some service to configure/reset the rest - have you tried SSH? If an authorized list is used you'd need to change your network address as well which could take days.

Comment: Always reset used servers like this to factory default.

Comment: I do not have a monitor, this is my problem, I asked how I can do so WITHOUT a monitor

Comment: @Maya Shouldn't really be too hard to GET a monitor... ;-)

Comment: even the cheapest gc could be put on for this activity

Answer (score 0):

You would need a monitor to set up iLo after resetting it. Not sure how that would work without a dedicated iLO port since the others could lead to a different web server on the OS.